# Parsing iOS/macOS localizable strings file with antlr4

Tags: xcode, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to parse the localized "strings" files of macOS/iOS.

The format of this file is based on key/value pairs, with optional comments. An example follows:

```
/* This is a comment */
// This is also a comment

"key1" = "value1";

"key2" = "value2";
```

and so on. **NOTE** inside the "" could be *absolutely any* kind of text.

**EDIT** Original errorneus grammar removed

I tried to write this simple grammar, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Since the contents inside the quotes could be quite tricky, not to mention the comments, I feel that usual regex has no real power there.

*EDIT* based on the comments by @GRosenberg I've created a new grammar. Now I have the problem that I can't include "Symbols" as a Char, or else parsing will break.

```
grammar LProj;

Esc         : '\\';
Spaces       : [ \t\r\n\f]+;
BlockComment   : '/*'  .*? ('*/' | EOF) ;
LineComment    : '//' ~[\r\n]* ( '\r'? '\n' [ \t]* '//' ~[\r\n]* )*  ;

MLN_COMMENT: BlockComment -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
SLN_COMMENT: LineComment  -> channel(HIDDEN) ;

doc : expression*;

expression
    :   BlockComment
    |   LineComment
    |   Spaces
    |   entry
    ;

entry : '"' key=VALUE '"' Spaces? '=' Spaces? '"' value=VALUE '"' Spaces? ';' ;


VALUE : ( EscSeq | Val )+ ;
fragment Val : Char ( EscSeq | Char )* ;

fragment Symbol
    :   '*'
    |   '/'
    |   ';'
    |   '='
    ;

fragment Char
    :   Spaces
    |   '!'         // skip "
    |   '#'..')'    // skip *
    |   '+'..'.'    // skip /
    |   '0'..':'    // skip ;
    |   '<'         // skip =
    |   '>'..'['    // skip \
    |   ']'..'~'
    |   '\u00B7'..'\ufffd'
    ;   // ignores | ['\u10000-'\uEFFFF] ;

fragment UnicodeEsc
    :   'u' (Hex (Hex (Hex Hex?)?)?)?
    ;

fragment Hex    : [0-9a-fA-F]   ;

fragment EscSeq
    :   Esc
        ( [btnfr"\\]    // standard escaped character set
        | UnicodeEsc    // standard Unicode escape sequence
        | .             // Invalid escape character
        | EOF           // Incomplete at EOF
        )
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Antlr grammar repository](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4), provides good examples of how to achieve the stated goal. Just define the `ID` terminal to allow for inclusion of escape sequences.

Thus (with obvious details omitted),

```
id    : QUOTE key=ID EQ val=ID QUOTE ;

DOC_COMMENT: DocComment   -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
MLN_COMMENT: BlockComment -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
SLN_COMMENT: LineComment  -> channel(HIDDEN) ;

NAME  : NameStartChar  NameChar* ;
VALUE : ( EsqSeq | Val )+ ;

fragment Val : NameStartChar ( EsqSeq | NameChar )* ;

fragment Hws            : [ \t]     ;
fragment Vws            : [\r\n\f]  ;

fragment DocComment     : '/**' .*? ('*/' | EOF) ;
fragment BlockComment   : '/*'  .*? ('*/' | EOF) ;
fragment LineComment    : '//' ~[\r\n]* ( '\r'? '\n' Hws* '//' ~[\r\n]* )*  ;

// escaped short-cut character or Unicode literal
fragment EscSeq
    :   Esc
        ( [btnfr"\\]    // standard escaped character set
        | UnicodeEsc    // standard Unicode escape sequence
        | .             // Invalid escape character
        | EOF           // Incomplete at EOF
        )
    ;

fragment Esc    : '\\'  ;
fragment UnicodeEsc
    :   'u' (Hex (Hex (Hex Hex?)?)?)?
    ;

// A valid hex digit
fragment Hex    : [0-9a-fA-F]   ;

fragment NameChar
    :   NameStartChar
    |   '0'..'9'
    |   '_'
    |   '\u00B7'
    |   '\u0300'..'\u036F'
    |   '\u203F'..'\u2040'
    ;

fragment NameStartChar
    :   'A'..'Z'
    |   'a'..'z'
    |   '\u00C0'..'\u00D6'
    |   '\u00D8'..'\u00F6'
    |   '\u00F8'..'\u02FF'
    |   '\u0370'..'\u037D'
    |   '\u037F'..'\u1FFF'
    |   '\u200C'..'\u200D'
    |   '\u2070'..'\u218F'
    |   '\u2C00'..'\u2FEF'
    |   '\u3001'..'\uD7FF'
    |   '\uF900'..'\uFDCF'
    |   '\uFDF0'..'\uFFFD'
    ;   // ignores | ['\u10000-'\uEFFFF] ;
```

Comment: Where have you taken this example from? The comments (i.e. DocComment) does not seem to be mentioned and I have issues properly integrating it.

Comment: Pieced here and there from the grammars, though mostly from the Antlr and Java grammars.

Comment: See edits. Best to just hide the comments from the lexer for later access if/when walking the parse tree.

Comment: I added the `channel(HIDDEN)` as proposed, but still no luck. I've updated my question to reflect this change.

Comment: `Symbol` is a fragment and never used. Not at all clear why inclusion of symbols in the `Char` definition would break anything given the problem definition at least as posted.  `BlockComment` and `LineComment` have to be fragments. If they are fragments, they cannot be matched in a parser rule.